# MQL4 to C++ dll on microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: c++, dll

How can I create a **DLL** file in ***Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community*** that can not be decompiled 
and transfer functions from my **mq4** indicator to the **DLL** file and connect them together?

I do not know any language other than **MQL4**

Comment: *"How can I create a DLL file that can not be decompiled"* Sorry, you have already lost there.

Comment: Do you mean that any DLL file can be decompiled?

Comment: Actually this kind of integration is not possible

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of any MQL programs being reverse engineered with the current compiler. The best way (in my opinion) in a DLL will be to write it in C++. Writing it in a DOTnet language will allow others to reverse engineer your code unless it is obfuscated. However, obfuscated code cannot be used to communicate with MT4.

Answer (score 0):

Current version of MetaEditor has "MQL5 Cloud Protector" option that adds encryption to already pretty good default anti reverse engineering protection of MLQ4/MQL5 executables making cracking it economically unjustified. It's cheaper to recreate algorithm and code it from scratch than to break into exec.

Comment: The problem with "MQL5 Cloud Protector" is that the indicator will work on any computer without the possibility of inserting a license that will work only on the account number of a specific customer. 
I transferred most of the information from the indicator to an MFC DLL file and wrote it in C ++
The question is whether this DLL file can be hacked and is it reliably protected from decompilation

Comment: You can insert licence info, like account number or account holder name into the MQL4 / MQL5 source code and then protect it with cloud protection. You will get personalized encrypted executable with better protection than you can provide with C++ dll IMHO.